# How to define "either...or"?

Tags: android, conditional-statements

I am trying to make a condition which, if `gettingupspeech` matches either one of the strings, the `if` function will set `resultText` to `"Correct! Press Next to move on."`

```
if(gettingupspeech.equals("5 more minutes Mum""five more minutes Mum")){
      resultText.setText("Correct! Press Next to move on.");
 }else{
      resultText.setText("That sounded off, please try again.");
 }
```

Comment: Please don't use the JavaScript tag when you're really referring to Java. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/245062/6296561

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's just a normal or.  So

```
if(gettingupspeech.equals("5 more minutes Mum") || gettingupspeech.equals("five more minutes Mum"))
```

If you have a bunch, you can put all the valid answers in a set and do

```
if(answersSet.contains(gettingupspeech))
```